# Trying to Use Transform to Rotate a UIView in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-graphics, transform, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIControl defined in which I have used the MonoTouch.CoreGraphics classes to draw some items in and have put the UIControl into a UIView through AddSubview.  I'm trying  to take the view and turn the whole thing to simulate something sort of like movement of the minute or second hand on a clock or a dial.  I'm under the impression that I can do that with the Transform on the UIView.

The name of my UIView is container.  I've tried:

```
    container.Transform.Rotate(-0.78f);
```

I have also tried:

```
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
    t.Rotate(-0.78f);
    container.Transform = t;
```

I have also tried:

```
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(-0.78f);
    container.Transform = t;
```

I have also tried this and other combinations of it:

```
    UIView.BeginAnimations("rotate");
    UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.5);
    container.Transform.Rotate((float)Math.PI);
    UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

None of the above have had any impact on my display.  It does not rotate or move in the slightest. All of the iOS related posts refer to CGAffineTransformRotate, but I can't find a Mono exact match for that and am assuming that is the equivalent of what I am doing above.  Is there some other way I should be trying to make my view rotate?

Comment: The equivalen to CGAffineTransformRotate is the CGAffineTransform.Rotate() method that rotates the affine you invoke it on.   So your code is correct.   The real issue is with "container".   What is it?

Can you share some code where you saw the effect that you were trying to replicate?

Comment: I am following an article on how to create a rotating wheel and porting it over to Monotouch.  I got the shape to draw and stopped at the part just trying to make it rotate using a timer.  Here is the link to the article http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit.  I have the DrawWheel method working fine in my UIControl class.  I create an instance of my wheel control and use AddSubview to add it to a UIView.  I'll be happy to send you all the code that I've written.  Just let me know where you'd like me to send it.

Comment: The easiest way to share your code would be to open a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach your code to it along with and a link to this question

Comment: I submitted bug 3679 and attached the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track.  I have a large game under development and do this all over the place in my code.  Here is the simplest example I can give you:

```
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;

float degrees = 15;
UIView aView = new UIView(new RectangleF(10,10,10,10));
aView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(3.14159f * degrees / 180f);
```

That's it.

The examples are sparse, especially the fact that the MakeRotation function is in radians (hence the use of pi to convert to degrees).

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  Turned out to be a couple of things.  1 was that it did not like me trying to use a timer to fire an event and do this.  Even when explicitly calling the code in a main thread it wouldn't do anything.  I also increased the size of the canvas I was using.  After I stopped using the timer and increased the size the above worked.

Comment: I have noticed that only the scheduled timers in MonoTouch work.  Try using a scheduled timer with 0d as your delay.